# grails - reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: grails, frame

I'm using frame in my page to get some data from the server.
When the page is loaded I noticed there are two calls passed to the server:
 
One in `NB_tans` action defined in the src frame and another one in  `tans` action defined anywhere in the page.

**HTML:**

```
...
<frame name="menu" src="/${grailsApplication.metadata.'app.name'}-${grailsApplication.metadata.'app.version'}/MyController/NA_tans" scrolling="auto">
...
```

**Groovy:**

```
def tans(){

    println "tans"

    ....

    render(view: "action",params:params)
    return

}


def NA_tans(){

    println "NA_tans"

    ....

    render(view: "action",params:params)
    return

}
```

**Output:**

```
tans
WARN: Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
NA_tans
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which Grails version you are using...
With `Grails 2.2.2` adding an empty model eg: `model:['':null]`  might resolve the bug.

Try:

```
render(view: "action", model:['':null], /* ... */)
```